# java keytool with opensc pkcs#11 provider only works with debug option enabled

Tags: java, smartcard, keytool, pkcs#11

I have the latest opensc 0.12.2 running on ubuntu 11.10 with OpenJDK ( java version "1.6.0_22")

I can read my smartcard (a Feitian ePass PKI) with

```
pkcs15-tool --dump
```

Now i try to use my smartcard with keytool:

```
keytool 
   -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 \
   -providerArg /etc/opensc/opensc-java.cfg \
   -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -list
```

which results in an error:

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:603)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:621)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:194)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:188)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKCS11 KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:696)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:600)
    ... 3 more
```

When i run the same command with debug options enabled like this:

```
keytool 
   -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 \
   -providerArg /etc/opensc/opensc-java.cfg \
   -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -list \
   -J-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11
```

it suddenly works:

```
... debug infos ...
Enter keystore password:  
sunpkcs11: login succeeded

Keystore type: PKCS11
Keystore provider: SunPKCS11-OpenSC

Your keystore contains 2 entries
...
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): ...
...
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): ...
```

The same behaviour when i configure it statically:

```
$ grep opensc /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/security/java.security
security.provider.7=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 /etc/opensc/opensc-java.cfg
```

and my config

```
$ cat /etc/opensc/opensc-java.cfg
name = OpenSC
description = SunPKCS11 w/ OpenSC Smart card Framework
library = /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

My guess it, it has something to do with openjdk or internal package `sun.security` which might usually not be used because it is an internal package. Activating Debug options might activate this internal package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the same problem today and I digged onto the java sources until I found the source of the problem. I know this question is quite old and already have an accepted answer, but that one is not a real answer.

Basically, the SunPKCS11 provider does list all available slots, then, get the slot you specified in your config, and give the error (since you do not specified any slot and fot its default value).

When in debug, after listing all available slots, it does list all slots with a smartcard inserted. After having print all these information about the slot list, *it does initialise* its slotid variable overwriting what you wrote (or forget to write) in your config. The new value is a correct one since it is read from the opensc defaults.

This is the relevant code from SunPKCS11.java from openjdk project:

```
    long slotID = config.getSlotID();
    // ....
        if ((slotID < 0) || showInfo) {
            long[] slots = p11.C_GetSlotList(false);
            if (showInfo) {
                System.out.println("All slots: " + toString(slots));
                slots = p11.C_GetSlotList(true);
                System.out.println("Slots with tokens: " + toString(slots));
            }
            if (slotID < 0) {
                if ((slotListIndex < 0) || (slotListIndex >= slots.length)) {
                    throw new ProviderException("slotListIndex is " + slotListIndex
                        + " but token only has " + slots.length + " slots");
                }
                slotID = slots[slotListIndex];
            }
        }
        this.slotID = slotID;
```

So, a workaround is to always include in your config a negative value like `slot = -1`, so that the provider will always look for the right one.

Comment: Great! You should post a bug report or patch to the jdk project

Comment: The `slot = -1` trick didn't work for me in my call to `keytool`.  But adding `-J-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11` to the command line did work.

Comment: @Hans-ChristophSteiner you've got a different bug. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039912

Comment: Confirmed in `openjdk-7-jdk:i386, 7u111-2.6.7-1`. Since I have both `openjdk7` and `Oracle JDK 7` installed, I first checked `keytool` was linked to the binary from Open JDK 7. Changed to Oracle JDK 7 and problem gone.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the debug flag to the command line worked for me:

```
keytool -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 \
  -providerArg /home/hans/Desktop/smartcards/opensc-java.cfg \
  -providerName SunPKCS11-OpenSC -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 \
  -list \
  -J-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11
```

Or manually specifying the slot in the cfg file:

```
name = OpenSC
description = SunPKCS11 w/ OpenSC Smart card Framework
library = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
slot = 2
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me in OpenJDK  1.8.0_144

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm this behavior using java JDK 1.6.0_20

Even a simple java program **only works** with -Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11 set.

```
String configName = "/etc/pkcs11_java.cfg";
Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
```

with /etc/pkcs11_java.cfg

```
name=OpenSC
description = SunPKCS11 via OpenSC
library=/usr/local/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
```